# No bootable device after sleeping

Tags: boot, hard-drive, suspend

My laptop (on Ubuntu 18.04) was showing a black screen of errors after being suspended for a few days:

```
Read-error on swap-device
EXT4-fs error (device sda2)
EXT4-fs error (device sda2)
...
```

I tried to reboot it, only to find "No bootable device". So I tried to reinstall Ubuntu, but couldn't - the hard drive was listed as only 1GB in the installation wizard.

I thought the hard drive must be corrupt, so I bought a new one and installed Ubuntu 20.04 - everything went well, I could reboot etc and it all seemed to be working. I left it suspended overnight, and this morning I came back to the same [black screen of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iq8Wg.jpg) as before. Also just like before, I'm unable to boot - "No bootable device".

Any ideas what's going on and how I can fix it? I can't keep buying a new hard drive every time I leave my laptop suspended!

Edit:
It thinks the hard drive is only 1GB in size. Output of `SMART`:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo smartctl -data -A /dev/sda -s on -T permissive
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-42-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

SMART support is: Unavailable - device lacks SMART capability.
=== START OF ENABLE/DISABLE COMMANDS SECTION ===
SMART Enabled.

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda -s on -T permissive
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-42-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     SM2259AB-10-00801000
Serial Number:    (03)5526888-20080228
Firmware Version: 20141211
User Capacity:    1,073,479,680 bytes [1.07 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 (minor revision not indicated)
Local Time is:    Fri Dec 11 12:45:21 2020 UTC
SMART support is: Unavailable - device lacks SMART capability.

=== START OF ENABLE/DISABLE COMMANDS SECTION ===
SMART Enabled.

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x00)     Offline data collection not supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0000) Automatic saving of SMART data                  is not implemented.
Error logging capability:        (0x00) Error logging NOT supported.
                    No General Purpose Logging support.

SMART Error Log not supported

SMART Self-test Log not supported

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported
```

Output of `fsck`:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck -y /dev/sda
fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

Output of `badblocks`:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo badblocks -v /dev/sda
Checking blocks 0 to 1048319
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test): done                                                 
Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned your OS & release details, but I would **not** try and boot it, instead boot a *live* system (eg. Ubuntu install media) and firstly check the health of your disk media using it's SMART (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools) then `fsck` and possibly `badblocks` the drive (I'd decide the badblocks after I'd evaluated the health using SMART; if the drive is dying I'd for sure not bother trying to fix it; instead use remaining life to recover any data you don't have good backups for...)

Comment: You mention a new drive; so I'd also check PSU/battery as good devices can malfunction with poor power, and also probably do generic hardware evaluation given a second device is giving you trouble (either your validation of issues was faulty, such as blaming devices when they misbehave because of missed PSU issues)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @guiverc - I've just updated my post with OS versions and the output from `SMART` and `fsck`. The output relates to the new hard drive, which is a day old (the old hard drive is not connected). It thinks the drive is only 1GB (it's actually 240GB), and fsck comes back with `Bad magic number in super-block`. Any ideas what to do next?

Comment: I suspect that `/dev/sda` is just an internal ubuntu partition and `/dev/sda2` would be the main partition on the disk? Unfortunately `/dev/sda2` isn't found.